# Data from api is diplayed only after refreshing the pages in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-services

I'm new to angular and I was working on an angular project. There is a problem I'm facing is that, after each component routing the data from is not displayed at first but after reloading the page the data is displayed as shown here [image: before reload]

[![after reload][2]][2].

and
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wn3Bv.png

the code used in service is

```
import { Injectable, SimpleChange } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

import { RouterModule, Routes, ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router'
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UserService {
    public userList = [];
    public userData = [];
    public header: any;
    public userkeypair: any;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient,
        private router: Router) {

        this.header = new HttpHeaders()
            .set("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')));
    }
    ListAlUsers() {
        this.http.get<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}GetAllEndUsers`, { headers: this.header })
            .pipe(map(rese => {
                return { rese }
            }))
            .subscribe((result: any) => {
                this.userList.push(result);
                this.userData = this.userList[0].rese;
                var stst: any;
                var useraary:any=[];
                for (let i = 0; i < this.userData.length; i++) {
                    if (this.userData[i].status == "True") {
                        stst = "Active";
                    } else {
                        stst = "Inactive";
                    }
                    this.userkeypair = {
                        "id": this.userData[i].id, "name": this.userData[i].fullName, "email": this.userData[i].emailId, "account": this.userData[i].relatedAccount,
                        "status": stst
                    }
                    useraary.push(this.userkeypair);
                }
sessionStorage.setItem('userlist',JSON.stringify(useraary));
            });
    }

}
```

and the component.ts is

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import{UserService} from './user.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index.component.css']
})
export class userComponent  {
public Userlst=[];
  constructor(private UserService:UserService) { 
    this.UserService.ListAlUsers();
    this.Userlst=JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('userlist'));
  }

  

}
```

please help me with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

James, your service shoud return observables, and you subscribe in component. If you want to make "something" with the response in service, use "tap". e.g.

NOTE:map is to transform the response, if you don't transform, not use it

```
ListAlUsers() {
   //see that you use "return"
   return this.http.get<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}GetAllEndUsers`, { headers: this.header })
            .pipe(tap(rese => {
               ..make what ever with the response..
               ..well, the code you has in subscribe...
             }
```

In your component

```
//see that you equal this.Userlst IN the subscribe function
this.UserService.ListAlUsers().subscribe(_=>{
    this.Userlst=JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('userlist'));
}
```

NOTE:You storage the value in SesionStorage, really you need'nt if you don't want that the value is maintein between sessions

**Update** about not in SessionStorage. We want the service return a data like `useraary`. So we use "map" to transform the value

```
ListAlUsers() :Observable<any>{ //<--I indicate thar return an Observable
   //see that you use return this.http.., yes! we return an observable
        return this.http.get<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}GetAllEndUsers`, { headers: this.header })
            .pipe(
            .map((result: any) => {
                //map can be so complex as we want
                this.userList.push(result);
                this.userData = this.userList[0].rese;
                var stst: any;
                const useraary:any=[]; //<--NOT use var, use const or let
                for (let i = 0; i < this.userData.length; i++) {
                    //I use a ternary operator instead an if
                    const stst=(this.userData[i].status == "True")?"Active":"Inactive"
                    this.userkeypair = {
                        "id": this.userData[i].id, "name": this.userData[i].fullName, "email": this.userData[i].emailId, "account": this.userData[i].relatedAccount,
                        "status": stst
                    }
                    useraary.push(this.userkeypair);
                }
                //and we simply return the value
                return useraary;
            });
    }
```

In our component

```
this.UserService.ListAlUsers().subscribe(response=>{
    this.Userlst=response
}
```

Comment: I got an error in my component.ts `Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Subscription'. Did you mean 'unsubscribe'?`.   Is there a way without using session storage. I mean the array value or any value which is in service to component and then to the html.  Can you demonstrate it with my code above

Comment: NOT, is `subscribe`, I updated the answer. See that we use "map" to transform the data. The "map" can be so complex as we need, only remember that you need return the value. NOTE: I don't revised your code. I suppose you can create temporaly variables instead of use a variable of your component like this.userList but I don't know much about your service

Comment: How can we pass an id from a service to another component's service after routing in button click?